# How Clear form fields with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use clone() and remove() with div elements. witch make div element clone .
In this div element i have filed

```js
$('.wrapper').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.element:not(:first):last').remove();
  setCloneButtonVisibility();
});

var cloneLimit = 12;

$('.wrapper').on('click', '.clone', function() {
  if ($('.results .element').length <= cloneLimit) { // just to make testing easier
    $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.element:first').clone().appendTo('.results');
  }
  setCloneButtonVisibility();
});

function setCloneButtonVisibility() {
  $('.wrapper .clone').toggle($('.results .element').length < cloneLimit);
}
  
  $('.2').val('');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element">
   <input  name="text" type="text" />
 
 </div>
  <div class="results"></div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="clone">clone</button>
    <button class="remove">remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

when i click clone it clones text filed.
But if i have typed text in filed and then i make clone in clone filed is same text witch i have in first filed. how make that every new clone field was  cleard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find `input` elements and set their value to empty.

```js
$('.wrapper').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.element:not(:first):last').remove();
  setCloneButtonVisibility();
});

var cloneLimit = 12;

$('.wrapper').on('click', '.clone', function() {
  if ($('.results .element').length <= cloneLimit) { // just to make testing easier
    $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.element:first').clone()
      // end() reverts last filtering operation
      .find(':input').val('').end().appendTo('.results');
  }
  setCloneButtonVisibility();
});

function setCloneButtonVisibility() {
  $('.wrapper .clone').toggle($('.results .element').length < cloneLimit);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element">
    <input name="text[]" type="text" />
    <!-- For demonstration of the :input pseudoselector -->
    <select name="sel[]">
      <option value="" />
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="results"></div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="clone">clone</button>
    <button class="remove">remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

References:

[`.end()`](https://api.jquery.com/end/)

[`:input`](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/#input1)

Answer (score 0):

how about set the value to null?

```
$('.wrapper').on('click', '.clone', function() {
  if ($('.results .element').length <= cloneLimit) { // just to make testing easier
    var input = $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.element:first').clone().find("input").val("");
input.appendTo('.results');
  }
  setCloneButtonVisibility();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var cloneLimit = 10;
var inputName = function makeid() {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  return text;
}


// handle click and add class
$('.remove').on("click", function(){
  $(this).parents('.wrapper').find('.results .element:eq(-1)').remove();
});

$('.clone').on("click", function(){
 var $clone = $(this).parents('.wrapper').find('.element:first').clone();
 $clone.find('input').attr('name',inputName());
 $clone.appendTo('.results'); 
});

$('.wrapper button').on('click', function(){
 if( $('.results .element').length < cloneLimit) {
   $('.clone').show();
 }
 else {
  $('.clone').hide();
 }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

input {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element">
   <input  name="text" type="text" />
 
 </div>
  <div class="results"></div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="clone">clone</button>
    <button class="remove">remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

i have made clone and remove button may be this is what you need..